# Interface cut jumps on load in simulator and iOS 8, but not on iOS 7 real device

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa, ios-simulator

I have a problem with my interface on iOS 8 GM(real 5s) and iOS 8 Simulator(iPhone 5, 5s, 6 and 6+).

When I'm testing the app and I load my custom player view controller, the interface make a jump when interface is shown. And when testing on real app, instead of jump MPVolumeView is appearing in a some kind of expanding animation.

However, the problem is not there when I'm testing it on iOS 7 iPhone(the real one).

Also I've found out that if I remove all the constraints from the view that is loaded the jump issue disappears.

May it be a bug in iOS 8 behavior? Or it is some new behavior that I'm getting wrong?

EDIT: Testing on iOS 7 simulator definitely makes it look like it's some new behavior of iOS 8(on iOS 7 it works fine).

Here is the video for better understanding of the problem:
(black bar is MPVolumeView)
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gfc3n2syqo4

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've figured it out.

For some reason, if you set constraint from the view to the bottom layout guide, the view will jump on load. Don't know if this is expected behavior, I think I will post bug report for this one.

TL;DR remove bottom layout guide constraint and use other constraints.